# Django: Check the data in a Django-admin form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Hello I have 2 models Sight and SightPic, The problem is that I want to make validation that will submit the form in only certain rules. I want to have only one picture to be is_front ==True and make validation of the form if there are more than one or none to throw an error

In My clean functuion if I

`print(len(images.filter(is_front=True)))` It will show me data that is not the data in the form but the data in the database (Which is normal) how can I check the data in the form?

models.py

```
class Sight(models.Model): 
       name=Charfield(...)
       description=Charfield(...)
       ...

class SightPicture(models.Model): 
       sight=ForeignKey(Sight)
       picture=ImageField(...)
       is_front=BooleanField
```

Admin.py

```
class SightPicInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = SightPicture
        fields = ("image_tag", "picture", "is_front")
        readonly_fields = ("image_tag",)

class SightAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        model = Sight
        inlines = [SightPicInline, ...., ....]




admin.site.register(Sight, SightAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override clean method for `ModelAdmin`:

```
from django import forms
class SightAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

     class Meta:
        model = Sight
        inlines = [SightPicInline, ...., ....]
     def clean(self):
        if Sight.objects.filter(is_front=self.cleaned_data.get("is_front")).exists():    
             raise forms.ValidationError("You can at max select one image as front")
        #more validations here
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: Yes OP wants to have only one picture with `is_front=True` @Aarif

Comment: If I do that returns me the already written data in the database but not the form data

Comment: @KostadinSlavov you can get the value of `is_front ` in form data by `self.cleaned_data.get("is_front")`

Comment: data from inline fields isn't available in `self.cleaned_data` @YugandharChaudhari

Comment: You will find the inline data `form.cleaned_data` in  on looping `self.forms`  @Aarif

Answer (score 0):

since inline models data isn't available in `self.cleaned_data` you can try and access inline models data from `self.data` property, add a form for `Sight` model admin and specify the form class in Model Admin `form=SightForm`

```
from django import forms

SightForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        start=self.data['sight_sightpicture-INITIAL_FORMS']
        end=self.data['sight_sightpicture-TOTAL_FORMS']
        front_images_count=0
        for i in range(start,end):
            is_front=self.data['sight_sightpicture-{}-is_front'.format(i)]
            if is_front:
                front_images_count+=1
            if front_images_count>1:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Error message here")
            return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: @Kostadin Slavov try this solution